# what is the error in my code ? I have not set the data already

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, opl, operations-research

i was trying to solve this transportation problem in cplex
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owKW8.png)

here is my OPL code

int p=...;

int q=...;

range i=1..p;

float a[i];

range j=1..q;

float b[j];

float c[i][j];

dvar boolean x[i][j];

minimize 
    sum(l in i,m in j)x[l][m]*c[l][m];

subject to {

forall (l in i)
  sum(m in j) x[l][m] <= a[l];

forall (m in j)
  sum(l in i) x[l][m] >= b[m];

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awror.png)
this is my .dat

I keep getting this error " Data element "a" is already set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you declare a in the .dat you should replace

```
float a[i];
```

by

```
float a[i]=...;
```